# How to see all environment variable in flask

Tags: python, environment-variables

How can I see all the environment variables in my flask application because when I was following a tutorial, instructor used "export FLASK_APP = app.py" command and then he went on to set other environment variables value. So, how can I see my all of the environment variables and their values ?

Comment: Check app.config

Answer (score 1):

To see wich env variables are set on your OS you can use the commands below,
env vars are variables on your OS and not a Flask specific vars, if the set with example with *export*.

Also there a .env files that are loaded or sometimes used by application like node where on .env files configuration specifc data is stored like keys, or urls.

on Linux

```
printenv
```

on windows (powershell)

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)

[an-introduction-to-environment-variables](https://medium.com/chingu/an-introduction-to-environment-variables-and-how-to-use-them-f602f66d15fa)